# Fielddata never gets evicted even though it uses more than indices.fielddata.cache.size

Tags: elasticsearch

We set `indices.fielddata.cache.size = '6gb'` but even though the field data cache uses more than that, evictions are never happening. The circuit breaker eventually triggers:

`"RemoteTransportException[[elasticsearch][inet[/0.0.0.0:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[org.elasticsearch.common.breaker.CircuitBreakingException: [FIELDDATA] Data too large, data for [myField] would be larger than limit of [9437184000/8.7gb]]; nested: UncheckedExecutionException[org.elasticsearch.common.breaker.CircuitBreakingException: [FIELDDATA] Data too large, data for [myField] would be larger than limit of [9437184000/8.7gb]]; nested: CircuitBreakingException[[FIELDDATA] Data too large, data for [myField] would be larger than limit of [9437184000/8.7gb]];`

All the field data settings:

```
indices.fielddata.cache.size: "6gb"
indices.breaker.fielddata.limit: "60%"
indices.breaker.request.limit: "30%"
indices.breaker.total.limit: "70%"
```

Here's what our field data size looks like for the cluster (call to `/_stats/fielddata?fields=*&human&pretty`):

```
"fielddata" : {
  "memory_size" : "168.1gb",
  "memory_size_in_bytes" : 180591558840,
  "evictions" : 0
},
```

From my understanding the max size should be capped at 6 gb * 24 nodes = 144 gb.

Comment: How much heap did you allocate for this node?

Comment: We allocate 16 Gb out of 32 Gb of RAM.

Comment: And how come `"memory_size" : "168.1gb"`?

Comment: I suspect you are looking at the total `fielddata` size (for the entire cluster). Take a look at per-node values. Also, what is the exact setting you have in `elasticsearch.yml` related to fielddata. Any other settings related to circuit breaker or fielddata. Please post them, if so.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I added more details.

Comment: I think that the `indices.fielddata.cache.size` is per node, and not per cluster. So, a better approach would be to look at the fielddata per node `GET /_nodes/stats/indices/fielddata` and see the values there. Then check the nodes that went pass the 6GB limit you set and double check the settings for that particular node. Also, can you post the complete log for one of the triggers?

Comment: I used that: `GET /_nodes/stats/indices/fielddata` and definitely found nodes that are above 6Gb: 
`"indices" : {
        "fielddata" : {
          "memory_size" : "8.4gb",
          "memory_size_in_bytes" : 9123604544,
          "evictions" : 0 } }`